# Does it improve performance to store the context in Android?

Tags: android, performance

In android, I've found that I make a lot of calls to:

 `getApplicationContext();`

Should I store the context in a variable instead of using the method to retrieve it each time?  Does it have a significant performance impact to keep calling this method as needed versus retrieving from a member?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You haven't given any example code showing why you need to call `getApplicationContext()` so many times. Also...are you actually sure you need the *application* `Context`? Do you know the difference between the `Context` of the application, an `Activity`, Service` etc etc? Are you sure you're not just calling `getApplicationContext()` unnecessarily because there is a lot of bad code out there written by bad coders telling you to do it?

Comment: `Context` is everywhere, `Context` is your app, and you want to save it? why? `Activity` is `Context`, a `View` is `Context`, dame! the screen is `Context`, this question is in android's `Context`, im quite sure my fingers/thinking  on android are `Context` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wouldn't improve perfomance, as `getApplicationContext()` complexity is `O(1)`.

That means that this method is really quick and you probably wouldn't notice the difference. However, you can store the value in a variable and use that multiple times, in order to improve the readability and manutenibility.